# Maintaining es6 class state over requests with express router

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I recently tried updating my project code structure with es6 classes in nodejs.

Here's what a controller class look like

```
class TaskController {
    constructor(io, redisClient) {
        this.socket = io;
        this.redisClient = redisClient;
    }

    create(req, res) {

        let taskDetails = req.body;

        taskDetails.owner = req.user.id;

        let errorFields = Validation.validate(taskDetails, [
            { name: 'title', type: 'text' }
        ]);

        if (errorFields.length > 0) {
            return ErrorHandler.handleError(res, errorFields);
        }

       ...`
    }
  }
```

and Here's how I'm initializing the class in a routes file

```
module.exports = (app, io, redisClient) => {
    let taskController = new TaskController(io, redisClient);

    router.post('', middlewares.isAuthorized('task:create'), taskController.create);

    app.use('/api/tasks', middlewares.isAuthenticated(), router);
  };
```

The problem is while hitting the **create** api the **this** object is undefined in the create function.

With a little debugging, I know that the constructor is called when registering the routes.

But the **taskController** looses context when the create function is actually called.

How can I make it work with this structure or do I have to revert back to 
module.exporting every function task controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bind method to bind context. while passing create function.

```
router.post('', middlewares.isAuthorized('task:create'), taskController.create.bind(taskController));
```

create method is losing context because it is getting called in different scope by post method.

You can bind context using bind method which returns a function and pass that function to create method.

Comment: Okay, so this works, but can you please explain how it is loosing context, I know the workings of bind but I don't understand how taskController looses context here. Routes are registering only once per application run time and at the time of registration taskController is good.

Comment: You were just passing reference of taskController.create to isAuthorized method which will execute the callback in its context, and hence this will refer to isAuthorized's context instead of taskController

Comment: Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind